# unduplicating similar data based on multiple fields

Tags: sql, oracle

I'd like to create a table of possible duplicate records from an original table, however the data is based on two different attibutes and they must only join in the same grouping id. Also in some cases the data doesn't look exactly the same (but the similarities are there). Here is what the original table would look like:

```
group_id| House_num | Apt    | code
----------------------------------
   45   | 1000      |  1     |  M
   45   |    1      |        |  D
   45   | 1000      |  2     |  M
   45   |    2      |        |  D
   87   | 2300      | 310    |  M
   87   | 2310      |        |  D
   87   | 2400      | 470    |  M
   87   | 2470      |        |  D
```

What I'd like to be returned is where these like numbers are all on the same row. So something like:

```
new_id  |group_id|a.house_num|a.apt|a.code|b.house_num|b.apt| b.code
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
   1    |   45   |   1000   |  1   |  M   |    1      |     |  D
   2    |   45   |   1000   |  2   |  M   |    2      |     |  D  
   3    |   87   |   2300   | 310  |  M   | 2310      |     |  D
   4    |   87   |   2400   | 470  |  M   | 2470      |     |  D
```

I'm not sure what kind of join to use here; also, im not sure how to get around the ones where a.house_num is the base number, a.apt is the suffixed number and b.housenumber is the combination of the two.   Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: I'm lost on how you are defining the rows in the result table.  Great:  they use two different attributes.  Do you want to specify what those attributes are and how they are used?

Comment: I will edit to try to give more info. The gist is the thing 1 number is a house number, while thing2 is the apartment number. what im finding are duplicates of houses based on the pattern above where in some cases they combine the two numbers; in others they change the apartment number to housing number.  i know that these are pretty much the same, but i dont know how to link them efficiently.

Comment: A solution starts with defining the algorithm. **Define the exact rules** when to consider two rows duplicates. For instance it seems that you consider it a duplicate when in a group one row's house number equals another's apt number. However, this is probably only true as long as the first row's app number and the second row's house number don't contradict. So, state exactly when you consider two rows duplicates and when not. With the list of these rules, it shouldn't be too difficult to write a related `ON` clause.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below to achieve your answer.**[The DB fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ab7c96b7d179e5b0d75117bd492379a2)**

```
        WITH data
         AS (SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE),
         data2
         AS (SELECT row_number()over 
             (order by thing1,thing2)    rw,
                    d1.group_id,
                    d1.thing1 a_thing1,
                    d1.thing2 a_thing2,
                    d1.thing3 a_thing3
             FROM   data d1
             WHERE  d1.thing3 = 'M'),
         data3
         AS (SELECT row_number()over 
                   (order by thing1,thing2)    rw,
                    d1.group_id,
                    d1.thing1 b_thing1,
                    d1.thing2 b_thing2,
                    d1.thing3 b_thing3
             FROM   data d1
             WHERE  d1.thing3 = 'D')
    SELECT d2.rw New_id,
           d2.group_id,
           d2.a_thing1,
           d2.a_thing2,
           d2.a_thing3,
           d3.b_thing1,
           d3.b_thing2,
           d3.b_thing3
    FROM   data2 d2,
           data3 d3
    WHERE  d2.group_id = d3.group_id
           AND d2.rw = d3.rw
```

Comment: Thanks for the attempt, but i think the results are random; there is a pattern in the above cases.  For example in new_id 1, one address i have is 1000 X street apartment 1, while the second is just 1 X street.  And in the case of id 4, we have 2400 X street apt 470, and 2470 X street.  for my purposes these are the same building, but we just got 2 different addresses for it.  I am trying to put these into the same rows so we can only mail to it once.

Comment: i have edited to generate rownum based on house_num

Answer (score 0):

```
create table t (group_id, House_num , Apt    , code) as
select   45   , 1000      ,  1     ,  'M' from dual union all
select   45   ,    1      , null   ,  'D' from dual union all
select   45   , 1000      ,  2     ,  'M' from dual union all
select   45   ,    2      , null   ,  'D' from dual union all
select   87   , 2300      , 310    ,  'M' from dual union all
select   87   , 2310      , null   ,  'D' from dual union all
select   87   , 2400      , 470    ,  'M' from dual union all
select   87   , 2470      , null   ,  'D' from dual;

select rownum new_id,
  a.GROUP_ID, a.HOUSE_NUM ahn, a.APT aapt, a.CODE acode,
              b.HOUSE_NUM bhn, b.APT bapt, b.CODE bcode
from t a
join t b
on a.group_id = b.group_id
  and a.code = 'M'
  and b.code = 'D'
  and (
    b.house_num = a.apt
    or b.house_num like '%'||a.apt
  );

NEW_ID GROUP_ID AHN  AAPT ACODE BHN BAPT BCODE
1      45       1000 1    M     1        D
2      45       1000 2    M     2        D
3      87       2300 310  M     2310     D
4      87       2400 470  M     2470     D
```